# "source()" not executing

Tags: c#, r, visual-studio, r.net

I'm trying to code a visual interface for some R scripts using R.NET, C# and Visual Studio. The R scripts work fine when executing them on RStudio. This is the code that gives problems:

```
StartupParameter rinit;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rinit = new StartupParameter();
    rinit.Quiet = true;
    rinit.RHome = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0";
    rinit.Interactive = true;

    REngine engine= REngine.GetInstance();
    REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\i386", @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0");

    engine.Evaluate("source('../../rsc/Rscripts/CargarPaquetes.r')");
    engine.Evaluate("source('../../rsc/Rscripts/IntroducirDatos.r')");
    engine.Evaluate("source('../../rsc/Rscripts/UnirTablas.r')");
    engine.Evaluate("PorcentajeEnfermedades<- prop.table(table(TablaTotal$Enfermedad))*100");

    var Porcentajes = engine.Evaluate("cbind(Frecuencia=table(TablaEntrenamiento$Enfermedad),Porcentaje=PorcentajeEnfermedades)").AsCharacter().ToArray();

    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(Porcentajes[0]));

    engine.Dispose();
}
```

Some code may be unnecessary, I don't understand at all how R.NET works and there isn't much documentation. The program don't stop running and I don't get any exception message, but the MessageBox never appears. When I execute the code step by step I see that the code is only executed from the beggining to `engine.Evaluate(@"source('../../rsc/Rscripts/CargarPaquetes.r')");`
(included). The rest of the lines are never executed and I can't figure out why.

By the way, if someone could recommend me any good documentation site for R.NET i would be very grateful.

**----EDIT----**

I created a button and moved all this code to the click event, and now the program stops and show the following error:

```
RDotNet.EvaluationException: 'Error in library(caret) : there is no package called 'caret'
```

The script "CargarPaquetes.r" basically loads a set of packages. I moved from R 3.5 to R 3.4, because R.NET gave some problems in the newer version...and now I have to deal with some bad installed packages.

Despite having solved the problem, it would be interesting to find out why the exeption was not called in the Load event.

Comment: my guess: try **rinit.Quiet = false;** to see more output

Comment: At first sight, anything changes.